# What does a value like node:{node_type} mean?

Tags: 8, routes

I'm trying to fully understand Drupal 8 routing. I understand the basics, no problem, but some of the finer details are still a mystery.

Here's the route for adding a node from the node module.

```
node.add:
  path: '/node/add/{node_type}'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\node\Controller\NodeController::add'
    _title_callback: '\Drupal\node\Controller\NodeController::addPageTitle'
  requirements:
    _node_add_access: 'node:{node_type}'
  options:
    _node_operation_route: TRUE
    parameters:
      node_type:
        with_config_overrides: TRUE
```

I'm struggling with the line `_node_add_access: 'node:{node_type}'`.

I understand what the `_node_add_access` key does. It refers to a service with a tag of `applies_to: _node_add_access`. That is provided by the `NodeAddAccessCheck` class.

What does the `node:{node_type}` do?  No amount of tracing through code has answered that for me. It looks to be a unique value for some purpose. Is it related to caching?

I haven't got to the options stuff yet.

Thanks

EDIT: I'm not sure if this should be an answer but these applies_to requirements seem to be read in `Drupal\Core\Access\CheckProvider::applies` and the value (e.g. node:{node_type}) doesn't seem to be used at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That definition isn't about what is *passed* to NodeAddAccessCheck, that is solely defined by the slug definition in the path and the type hinted argument.

Instead, it is configuration for its implementation. Which it doesn't actually use. So yes, it is pointless. See `\Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityCreateAccessCheck` for an access check that actually uses that definition to dynamically get the value it wants from the route match parameters.

I suppose this initially used that and was switch to a different implementation, without removing the now unnecessary configuration.

Comment: Thanks, that explains it. I got onto this because I was studying a contrib module and noticed it doing the same thing but not using the value.

Answer (score 0):

`{node_type}` is a slug and is available as the `$node_type` param in `NodeAddAccessCheck::access()`

https://www.drupal.org/node/2186285

Comment: I thought that too but I don't think that's it. There's an arguments resolver which gets the node_type from the request. I can replace `node:{node_type}` in the yml with something completely bogus ('xxx') and it still works. NodeAddAccessCheck::access() still receives a NodeType object.